# SQL Select rows that match multiple criteria from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following table:

```
+-------------+------------+----------+---------+
| alarminc_no | cust_name  | event_id | site_no |
+-------------+------------+----------+---------+
|       99999 | Jonh Smith | UYALR    |    9090 |
|       99999 | Jonh Smith | UYBR     |    9090 |
|       99999 | Jonh Smith | PAF      |         |
|       77777 | Allan      | UYBIC    |    9090 |
|       77777 | Allan      | UYBR     |    9090 |
|       77777 | Allan      | PAF      |    9090 |
|       88888 | Susan      | UYGR     |    9090 |
|       88888 | Susan      | UYLAR    |    9090 |
|       88888 | Susan      | PAF      |    9090 |
+-------------+------------+----------+---------+
```

I need to extract ONLY the rows that match this criteria:

event_id must contain certain values ONLY, for example, must contain UYALR and PAF.

Heres the real table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp3ax.png)

As you can see, every alarminc_no has a lot of eventids, I only need to see the alarminc_no that has PAF or PFA as eventID, and ALSO the following EventIDS only:

```
'PAF','PFA','USABA','USALR','USBUR','USDUR','USFIR','USPAN','USTAM','UYALR','UYAVI','UYBUR','UYDIR','UYDUR','UYE73','UYFIR','UYMED','UYPAN','UYTAM'
```

So, if an alarminc_no has PAF in event ID but none of the others IDS, or others that are not these, then I dont want it on the output.

Sorry for the mess, Im trying my best to explain this mess.

Comment: Can you share what your expected output would be?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your response.

I only need two values to show up, values with PAF and PFA in event ID.

For example, for every alarminc_no there are multiple eventIDs, could be:

alarminc_no           user            eventID

999999999           Jon               UYBR
999999999           Jon               UYCL
999999999           jon               PAF

I only want the alarminc_no that have certain event_ids associated with them, such as PAF and UYCL, and exclude everything else.
999999999
999999999

Comment: If a user has a record for event_id = UYALR and a record for event_id = PAF, do you want to select both records?

Comment: @Demian are `alarminc_no | cust_name` enough in the output?

Comment: So only the PAF and PFA records are to come into the output, and then only if there is a PAF and UYALR record, but not a UYLOL record for that paricular `alarminc_no`.

Comment: Also, for 88888 user id there are two different names present

Comment: I only need to get every alarminc_no that has this list of eventIDs:

'PAF','PFA','USABA','USALR','USBUR','USDUR','USFIR','USPAN','USTAM','UYALR','UYAVI','UYBUR','UYDIR','UYDUR','UYE73','UYFIR','UYMED','UYPAN','UYTAM'

But, if the alarminc_no have maybe 8 of this eventsID (wich I want) but one that I dont want, then I dont want it in the output.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that, every alarminc_no has the same user associated, i should edit the first post.

Comment: To clarify:

I need the eventID's PAF and PFA, that ONLY has this other eventID associated via alarminc_no:

'USABA','USALR','USBUR','USDUR','USFIR','USPAN',‌​'USTAM','UYALR','UYA‌​VI','UYBUR','UYDIR',‌​'UYDUR','UYE73','UYF‌​IR','UYMED','UYPAN',‌​'UYTAM'

so, If an alarminc_no has the following eventIDs: PAF UYFIR UYPAN, then is good.
But is an alarminc_no has the following eventIDS: UYFIR UYPAN, then is not good since PAF or PFA are not present.
Also, if alarminc_no has the following EventIDS: UYFIR PAF BRLL, then is not good too cause BRLL is not in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT alarmic_no 
FROM (
  SELECT alarmic_no,
     CASE WHEN eventid in
       ('PAF','PFA','USABA','USALR','USBUR','USDUR','USFIR','USPAN','USTAM',
        'UYALR','UYAVI','UYBUR','UYDIR','UYDUR','UYE73','UYFIR','UYMED',
        'UYPAN','UYTAM') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BAD,
     CASE WHEN eventid in ('PAF','PFA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS GOOD
  FROM tablename
) X
GROUP BY alarmic
HAVING SUM(BAD) = 0 AND SUM(GOOD) > 0 AND COUNT(*) > 1
```

---

*update based on comments*

```
SELECT *
FROM MYTABLE 
JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT alarminc_no, system_no
  FROM (
    SELECT alarminc_no,system_no,
       CASE WHEN event_id in
         ('PAF','PFA','USABA','USALR','USBUR','USDUR','USFIR','USPAN','USTAM',
          'UYALR','UYAVI','UYBUR','UYDIR','UYDUR','UYE73','UYFIR','UYMED',
          'UYPAN','UYTAM') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BAD,
       CASE WHEN event_id in ('PAF','PFA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS GOOD
    FROM MYTABLE
    where event_date between '01/12/2016' and '31/12/2018'
  ) X
  GROUP BY alarminc_no, system_no
  HAVING SUM(BAD) = 0 AND SUM(GOOD) > 0 AND COUNT(*) > 1
) X ON MYTABLE.alarmic_no = X.alarmic_no AND MYTABLE.system_no = x.system_no
```

Comment: Sorry for this noob question, im putting your code like this in MSSQLManagement studio but it tells me bad sintaxys near the word "not" :(

Comment: @Demian -- ok I took out the not (and changed the values so change that too)

Comment: Now it says bad sintaxys near "in", Im copy and pasting, I only change the tablename

Comment: oh yeah I forgot the `WHEN`

Comment: There, is running!.
Can we limit the query to a specified date? i was using: event_date > '01/12/2016' and event_date < '31/12/2018'

Comment: @Demian sure... just use a where clause.

Comment: Hi!
Im testing your code and the output shows me duplicated results, is there any way to group the alarminc_no and in another row have the Number of PAF and PFA of each one?.
I tried to do it but as I say im almost a beginner in this, I tried also to add event_date column and event_id column in your query to have them in the output but it shows me empty results. Thanks again!!

Comment: This is the code:   `SELECT alarminc_no, system_no
FROM (
  SELECT alarminc_no,system_no,
     CASE WHEN event_id in
       ('PAF','PFA','USABA','USALR','USBUR','USDUR','USFIR','USPAN','USTAM',
        'UYALR','UYAVI','UYBUR','UYDIR','UYDUR','UYE73','UYFIR','UYMED',
        'UYPAN','UYTAM') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BAD,
     CASE WHEN event_id in ('PAF','PFA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS GOOD
  FROM MYTABLE
  where event_date > '01/12/2016' and event_date < '31/12/2018'
) X
GROUP BY alarminc_no, system_no
HAVING SUM(BAD) = 0 AND SUM(GOOD) > 0 AND COUNT(*) > 1;`

Comment: @Demian -- I also don't want to look at unformulated code in comments -- you want to post code make a new question or use gist.github.com

Comment: Im sorry, I will try your suggestion, its my frist time asking here.
Thanks for the tip of github.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8f9e19dfd04c4ac127e48d9f872e0aa2

Comment: @Demain -- here you go, I show you how to get all the columns from mytable based on the results: https://gist.github.com/hoganlong/3033e159c9501163f3bb166eae2249fb

Comment: Thank you very much, im testing it and it seems to work (some results don't show up but im looking into it), the thing I cant seem to fix is that for some reason, in the output the fields system_no and alarm_inc appears two times, do you know why?.
Sorry for this many questions :(

Comment: @Demian - you have exactly the query I have as the 2nd query?

Comment: Hi Hogan, thanks for the reply, Im baffled with this. Yes, I copied it exactly, I only changed the "mytable".
The strange thing is (besides the duplicated collumns) that some results (that matchs with the conditions) don't show up in the output, and I dont know why, cause a lot of other results (that also match with the conditions) shows up perfectly.
The only thing I can note in the ones that don't show up, is that they have a LOT of event IDS some multiple UYBUR and such, and the results that i got in the output have little eventIDs, maybe only 2 (UYBUR and PAF).

Comment: Here, this result shows up in the output with the code, and have the conditions (ends in PAF or PFA and has one or more of the values in the list):

http://imgur.com/a/PxC7E

///////   But, this one, that also have the conditions (ends in PAF or PFA and has at least one or more of the values from the list) do not shows up in the output:

http://imgur.com/a/N4tFm

/////////  Again, thank you for your help and your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Demian -- your rules state if there any event_id that are not in your list don't show that one.  I quote you: "or others that are not these, then I dont want it on the output." -- This is the case here -- **in fact the first one** has a event_id of UYCAN which is not in your acceptable list.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry, I explained it wrong then, sorry, English is not my main lang, I will try again to explain it..
I need in the output only the alarminc_no that have PAF and PFA, and some (could be 1 or more) of the values of the list.
It doesnt matter if the alarminc_no has UYCAN in the eventid or any other value, as long as PAF and PFA are present, and that some of the values in the list are also present.
Sorry for the confusion, I spend days in this and can't think straight, you code really help me a lot.

Comment: I can make a new question if you want with this new explanation if it's clear, thank you again!.

Comment: ok then you just need to change the HAVING clause to `HAVING SUM(GOOD) > 0 AND COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(*) <> (SUM(GOOD)+SUM(BAD))` -- maybe it might help to understand why this works.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you alarminc_no for the users that have UYALR and PAF but not UYLOL.

```
select alarminc_no
from your_table
group by alarminc_no
having count (
    distinct case when
        event_id in ('UYALR','PAF')
    then event_id end
) = 2 and count (
    case when event_id = 'UYLOL' then 1 end
) = 0;
```

Comment: Yes, this is I think is what I need, I just would need to put all the eventid I dont want in "case when event_id = 'UYLOL' then 1 end" correct?.
Also, there is some way to group the results and count the PAF and PFA only?

Comment: @Demian that's correct. And yes, you can add a similar test for those two too.

Comment: Hi, im testing your code now, the other one misses some results (some event with PAF and UYALR do not show up in the output for some reason), one question, is possible in your code to have in the output also the field event_id, event_date and system_no? all that values (collumns) are in the same table, lets call it "your_table".
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Those alarminc_no won't show up which have at least one OYLOL as per your requirement

Comment: I see, the problem is that I need the event that contains UYLOL if also contains PFA, PAF or UYALR.
So, is there any way to tell SQL to select ONLY the alarminc_no that have for example PAF and PFA and UYALR, ignoring if this events have others IDS?.